# SCD type 2 dimension - how to grap multiple value versions under single category

Tags: database-design, architecture, powerbi, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

*What is concidered the best practice for having SCD type 2 and still being able to group facts by the latest value? How can I GROUP BY COUNTRY on Power BI side ignoring COUNTRY changes (Macedonia and N. Macedonia should be the same category)?*

Suppose in the following example, I want to keep the history of POPULATION changes, but still be able to group metrics by COUNTRY ignoring changes.

### Example

*Dimension:*

```
SR  |  COUNTRY (SCD1) | POPULATION (SCD2) | START_DATE | END_DATE
1        Macedonia         100,000        | 2001-09-03 | 2015-07-01
2        Macedonia         110,000        | 2015-07-01 | 2019-07-01
3        N. Macedonia      110,000        | 2019-07-01 | NULL
```

*Fact table:*

```
SR | METRIC_1 | METRIC_2
1  | 10       | 100   
1  | 20       | 110   
2  | 30       | 120
3  | 40       | 130
```

Now I want to get the following report:

```
COUNTRY   | SUM(METRIC_1)
Macedonia   100              # SR key 3 was taken into account despite COUNTRY value is different!
```

### Workarround

The solution we found - is to handle some columns as SCD 2, but overwrite other columns during ETL transformation (handle them as SCD 1)

```
SR  |  COUNTRY (SCD1) | POPULATION (SCD2)
1        N. Macedonia      100,000           # old COUNTRY value was overwritten
2        N. Macedonia      110,000           # old COUNTRY value was overwritten 
3        N. Macedonia      120,000
```

*Is this a common practice for handling such scenario? Or there are better approaches? Maybe adding another group column top dimension?*

Comment: The "business key" changed here as the country name changed. Given that it is the same geographical region, your workaround should be OK. May also add country code and use that as business key and in queries (`WHERE CC3 = 'MKD'`)

Comment: add a start and end date column, and a current flag column

Comment: @Jonee added, thanks! IMHO current flag isn't needed, we can use END_DATE = NULL criteria, right?